# Volumetric Soil Water to Gravimetric Moisture

Tags: soil-moisture

I have a dataset from ERA LAND with a Volumetric Soil Water (m3 m<sup>-3</sup>), How I could convert to a Gravimetric Moisture content (kg kg<sup>-1</sup>)?

Answer (score 1):

Use bulk densities of water and the ground in question.

Density, ρ, is mass divided by volume.

$\ \ \rho \ = \ \frac{m}{V}$

Rearrange the equation to get mass, density times volume.

Depending on how fancy you want get, by making allowances for temperature and impurities, the density of water of 1 g/cm<sup>3</sup> (1 t/m<sup>3</sup> or 1000 kg/m<sup>3</sup>).

You next need to know the basic geology of the region in question and use appropriate values of [density](https://www.structx.com/Soil_Properties_002.html).